# SpannableStringBuilder only keeping formatting for the first for loop

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spannablestringbuilder

I am trying to use a for loop to add formatting using `SpannableStringBuild` from strings in a list, however in the `TextView`, despite all the strings having been appended, only the string appended in the initial for loop keeps its formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can't reuse instance of formatting style twice, all that had to be done was move the declaration of the formatting such as `UnderlineSpan underlineSpan = new UnderlineSpan();` inside the for loop.